# How to pass some data from current html page to controller on button click as an argument for another api call in springboot thymleaf?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have one html page which contains some data. There is also one button on the same page, when we click that button a new api is called.
I want to pass some data from the displaying page as a RequestParam or RequestBody to another api on button click.
I am new to thymleaf and UI technology. Could someone please suggest how should I achieve this?

the main api is : http:localhost:8080/home

- There is some data on this page.
- Also we have one button on this page.

I want to send some of the data which is being displayed on page to the another api which gets called after clicking a button.

Api called on button click: http:localhost:8080/data/export  (GET api)

Answer (score 0):

Example of sending a string as a RequestParam from a thymeleaf page.

```
@GetMapping("/data/export")
public String exportData(@RequestParam(name = "myData") String myData) {
    // do stuff
}
```

---

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/data/export}" th:method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="myData" th:value="*{myData}" />
    <button type="submit" id="submitButton">Button</button>
</form>
```

There will need to be an object called "myData" on your page in order for the input to have the right value.
If you're referencing a property from an object you'll need to include `th:object` in the form. In this example it would look like so

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/data/export}" th:object="myObject" th:method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="myData" th:value="*{myData}" />
    <button type="submit" id="submitButton">Button</button>
</form>
```

Where `myObject` has a property called `myData`

[Reference for passing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716052/thymeleaf-pass-input-text-as-parameter-in-form-action#45716697)

[Reference for the button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370011/thymeleaf-button-click-to-call-http-delete-method)